# How to get day from what event has been moved from in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am registered for receiving updates with Google Calendar API. But there is a problem when user moves event from one day to another. For example from 24/08/14 to 21/08/14.

I would get the update that events has been changed on 21/08/14, but I can't see any way to find out from which date the event has been moved from, so I can find the event on my side.

P.s.
I am develoing a system that works with GOOGLE Calendar API and another System API, and I don't have required functionality in the SYSTEM API too, so it would be handy if there is any way to find out the way to find out from which date the event has been moved from.

Answer (score 0):

Use event IDs to match the events you have in the system and the updated events. That way you can happily track the changes.

Comment: Thank you Luc, but unfortunately my external system don't allow to search by google event id. Only by internal id. Of course db on my side would be a solution, but it doesn't looks very elegant for now. But thank you for suggestion any way!